# regex: word index in string

Tags: python, regex, indexing, substring, cpu-word

given a big string:

```
str = "Include all the information someone would need to answer your question ... ..."
```

how to get the index of a whole word in this string by mean only of python code and regex (not lists and the like); this index is the index of this word if it was an element in the list:

```
lst = str.split()
```

in which: the index of the word "information" is 3, and of "answer" is 8.

Comment: Can you please explain the question in more detailed way.

Comment: You mean `str.split().index('information')`? Why reinvent the wheel with `re` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to return your `Index` in this way, but maybe something like:

```
Indx = re.findall(r'^.*\binformation\b', str)[0].count(' ')
```

or:

```
Indx = re.search(r'^.*\binformation\b', str).group(0).count(' ')
```

This would return the position/index of the word information.

Comment: what if i need all the positions?